# hyperlink: set onClick

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Good day,

I have an hyperlink

```
 Click in this ¿ <a href="#" id="hr" class="alert-link"><strong>Link</strong> ?</a>
```

I want to use a [bootstrap alert](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#alerts-dismissible) that OnClick uses a Javascript function. How can I do it?

I tried doing something like this but it did not work.

```
Click in this ¿ <a href="#" OnClick="myfuncti()"id="hr" class="alert-link"><strong>Link</strong> ?</a>
```

thank you.

Comment: So you want to open an alert on click of link ?

Comment: Just use `onclick="alert("message")"`

Comment: I want to call a function after I click on the hyperlink, the altert belongs to boostrap and is already showing

Comment: Your question is incomplete. Not sure what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is, if you want a function, add the following `onclick` attribute:

```
<a href="#" onclick="function()" id="hr" class="alert-link"><strong>Link</strong> ?</a>
```

Also make sure that your JS and HTML files are correctly linked, and your function name matches the one you're calling.

Comment: thank you, but I am afraid the code is not working, it seems that the href is more important than the onclick event...so when I click on the hyperlink, it does not trigger the function.

Comment: Maybe set the hyperlink to just a blank string, like `href=""`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```js
function myfunction(){
  //do what you want...
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="hr" class="alert-link" onclick="myfunction()"><strong>Link</strong> ?</a>
```

Comment: thank you, but I am afraid the code is not working, it seems that the href is more important than the onclick event...so when I click on the hyperlink, it does not trigger the function.

Answer (score 0):

Anchor tag in itself has an action on it , so your callback function should have a preventDefault method for it to work.

For e.g

```
<a href="#" onclick="foo()" id="hr" class="alert-link"><strong>Link</strong> ?</a>

function foo() {
 event.preventDefault();
}
```

```js
 
    function foo() {
     event.preventDefault();
     console.log("hello")
    }
```

```html
    <a href="#" onclick="foo()" id="hr" class="alert-link"><strong>Link</strong> ?</a>
```